# Export Excel in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-excel

I want to export the page Info to Excel ,who can tell me how can i do this?
    thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, I checked out a few options to do exactly this and wound up using the spreadsheet gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet). The documentation is a bit meh, but it is quite powerful and I was able to extend it to fit my needs.

Comment: please google next time first (e.g 'rails export to excel' gives You same pages as people put for You in the comment section ;) )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this might help:

http://blog.dhavalparikh.co.in/2009/04/export-to-excel-in-ruby-on-rails/

**Controller**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def export
    headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.xls"'
    headers['Cache-Control'] = ''
    @users = User.find(:all)
  end
```

**View**

```
export.html.erb

<%= link_to "Export as Excel", export_person_url %>

_report.html.erb

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <% @users.each do |u| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= u.name %></td>
  <% end %>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for you help! now i use the spreadsheet plugin to solve the problem